# Print out/read Problems with the Read Function using PySerial

Tags: python, networking, serial-port, pyserial

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pODWF.png)

I'm trying to work with PySerial and the Code itself works fine, but the Output I get after pushing the Code to my Switch via Serial Connection, is very random as you can see in the linked Picture. The output/things I pushed get reflected in those messy outputs, but it would be nice, if someone knows a Solution to my problem.
Any help appreciated...

I haven't really found a Solution to this online and I have no Idea, what I could change in my Code to solve this issue...